# Can I brew link only files without conflicts?

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, imagemagick-convert

Is there a way to `brew link` just those files without conflicts?

As near as I can tell, the only options are to force an overwrite of all conflicting roles, or to link no files at all. For example I have an existing `compare` that I need to keep, but need ImageMagick's `convert`. When I `brew install imagemagick` I get

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/compare
Target /usr/local/bin/compare
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/compare'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite imagemagick

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/compare -> /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

But the only way offered to proceed is either to leave *all* of ImageMagick unlinked, or to overwrite my existing `compare`.

How do I `brew link` everything but the existing `compare`? Is there a way to install only `convert` perhaps?

Comment: As a patch, for now: `ln -s "/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare" /usr/local/bin/acompare`.

Comment: There’s no way to do that using Homebrew only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell function I wrote to do this (for the *zsh* that's now standard on macOS, but it will run on Bash with small adjustments <sup>1</sup>):

```bash
local targetdir
targetdir=($(brew --cellar $1)/*/bin) || return
local linksdir=$(brew --repo)/bin

for ex in "$targetdir"/*(^/)        # files (and symlinks), not subdirectories
do
    local exname=${ex##*/}
    if builtin which "$exname" &>/dev/null
    then
        echo "  $exname already available in the path - skipped"
    else
        ln -s "$ex" "$linksdir/" && echo "$exname linked from $linksdir"
    fi
done
```

I saved it as a [shell function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html) called `blink` and when I call it with a package name, like

```
blink binutils
```

it symlinks only the binaries whose names aren't already available in the $PATH.

<sup>1</sup><sub>The adjustments to make it work on Bash: remove the final `(^/)` form the `for ex...` line, and the `builtin` 3 lines further down.</sub>